# SQL Server receiving email from outside

Tags: sql-server

Need to know whether we can send email to a SQL Server database, So that it stores the email and extracts the attachment from the email to form a table in the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

No, SQL Server is a database designed for storing, querying and managing the data.

You need to break the problem down in to the different components of the system that you need to handle, specifically I see:

- Receive email via SMTP
- Fetch email via POP or IMAP
- Process email
- Store in database

So this would give you 3 components:

- Mail server
- Database
- Service

The service is the part you need to write, so you'll be wanting to research how to fetch and parse emails from a mail server and how to run your application as a service.

If you're using C# I would suggest [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/) and [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).